# Impossible to connect to a MongoDB Deployment

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a simple NodeJS project which is supposed to connect to a MongoDB server:

```
const express        = require('express');
const MongoClient    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const db             = require('./config/db');

const app            = express();

const port = 8030;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
console.log(db.url)
MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err, database) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err)

    require('./app/routes')(app, database);
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Server is listenning on port 8030....');
    });
});
```

variable `db.url` contains
`mongodb://test:test@ds147421.mlab.com:47421/testnode` where `test` is a database user username and `test` is his password.

I have this error thrown:

```
{ [MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds147421.mlab.com:47421] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to ds147421.mlab.com:47421 timed out]]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [ds147421.mlab.com:47421] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to ds147421.mlab.com:47421 timed out]' }
```

I don't know what I've done wrong here.

Any idea ?

Comment: the error says port 62919 not 47421

Comment: My bad that was the wrong error. I updated it

Comment: can you connect to the db with a local client from the command line. You can start there and then return to the node issue.

Comment: works for me. check with telnet if any firewall blocks it.

Comment: Maybe it's because of my corporate network ? @AlexBlex

Comment: I am not aware about your corporate network yet. Testing transport layer with telnet will help to find it out.